# Given $A$ is Hermitian, Show that a given $U$ is unitary

Tags: linear-algebra, unitary-matrices, hermitian-matrices

Let $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ be Hermitian. Show that the matrix $U=(A+iI)^{-1}(A-iI)$ is a unitary matrix.

I have done so far: We want $U^*U=I$, so finding $U^*$

\begin{align}U^*&=((A+iI)^{-1}(A-iI))^*\\
&=(A-iI)^*((A+iI)^{-1})^*\\
&=(A^*+iI)((A+iI)^*)^{-1}\\
&=(A^*+iI)(A^*-iI)^{-1}\\
&=(A+iI)(A-iI)^{-1}\end{align}

Then we know that $U^*U=(A+iI)(A-iI)^{-1}(A+iI)^{-1}(A-iI).$

This is where I am stuck as im not sure how to manipulate $U^*U$ to show that it is $I$ given that matrices in general are not commutative.

Answer (score 1):

$(A+iI)$ does commute with $(A-iI)^{-1}$ because
\begin{aligned}
(A+iI)(A-iI)^{-1}
&=(A-iI)^{-1}\left[(A-iI)(A+iI)\right](A-iI)^{-1}\\
&=(A-iI)^{-1}\left[(A+iI)(A-iI)\right](A-iI)^{-1}\\
&=(A-iI)^{-1}(A+iI).
\end{aligned}
Alternatively, by Cayley-Hamilton theorem, $X^{-1}$ is a polynomial in $X$. Therefore $(A-iI)^{-1}$ is a polynomial in $A-iI$. In turn, it is a polynomial in $A$. Hence it commutes with every polynomial in $A$ and with $A+iI$ in particular.

Comment: I am unclear on why we are able to swap $(A-iI)(A+iI)$ with $(A+iI)(A-iI)$ going from line 1 to line 2

Comment: @Alison it may be that a change in notation helps you.  A standard group theory approach is to note for invertible $Y$ then $XY=YX\implies XY^{-1}=Y^{-1}X$.  The proof is one line:     
$XY^{-1}= \big(Y^{-1}Y\big)XY^{-1}= Y^{-1}\big(YX\big)Y^{-1} = Y^{-1}\big(XY\big)Y^{-1} = Y^{-1}X\big(YY^{-1}\big) =Y^{-1}X$

Answer (score 0):

$(A-iI)^{-1}$ commutes with $A$ and hence also with $A+iI$. Proof:

$(A-iI)^{-1}(A-iI)=I$ so $(A-iI)^{-1}A=I+i(A-iI)^{-1} $. Similarly,

$(A-iI)(A-iI)^{-1}=I$ so $A(A-iI)^{-1}=I+i(A-iI)^{-1}$. Since the right sides of these two equatins are the same we get  $(A-iI)^{-1}A=A(A-iI)^{-1}$.  So  $(A-iI)^{-1}$ commutes with $A$. Hence it also commutes with $A+iI$.

Thus $(A+iI)(A-iI)^{-1}(A+iI)^{-1}(A-iI)=(A-iI)^{-1}(A+iI)((A+iI)^{-1}(A-iI)=I$.

Comment: Are there details or some result to show that $(A-iI)^{-1}$ commutes with $A$ and $A+iI$?

Comment: I have proved this in my answer. Do you have difficulty with the proof?  @Alison

Comment: I misread, apologies

Comment: Yes I am having difficulty following the proof @Kavi

Comment: @Alison There were several typos in my answer. Sorry about that. I have edited my answer